# Soft delete but cannot prevent delete cascade with foreign key table

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

My entity user with @SQLDelete

```
    @Data
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "`user`")
    @SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE `user` SET status = 0 WHERE id = ?")
    public class User {
        private Integer id;
        private String username;
        private String password;
        @ManyToMany
        @JoinTable(
                name = "`user_role`", 
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), 
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
        private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
        
    }
```

When I delete by method `userRepository.deleteAllById(ids)`. My row user_role table also deleted. I only want soft delete a row at user table and no effect to user_role

Comment: Duplicate query: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412817/prevent-delete-from-cascading-to-an-entity-instance

Comment: It's not working for me